# change mouse button function

Tags: c#, electron, mouse

i've new mouse gaming that have several additional button. this mouse doesn't include application to allow user modifying function for the button. i like to change just like **sharpkeys** do. If there's any application that can allow me, can you tell me what is it? Or if there's no application yet, i im interested to starting developing.
for development choice, i've 2 option, develop with electron(javascript) or c#(the same programming language used by sharpkeys). can you recommend me which one is better?

update:

from this following link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

we can detect that every button has their own key code, my mouse button additional key code is 3 and 4. how can i modify these key become a same function like home/end in my computer keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state clearly about what you want to achieve.

1. Press a mouse button and act like "go to top of the page" ( what home key does ).
2. Press a mouse button and act like press home, and press home is defined by yourself.

I'll try to answer both.

According to your link, I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

For solution 1.

You need mouse button act as "go to the top of page", you shall dig about how to "go to 
 the top of page".

For solution 2.

Keyboard event will tell you which key is pressed.
 You may route mouse event and keyboard event to the same function.

Answer (score 0):

i'm also found other application for alternatives for the solution to my problem, It's Mouse Manager. However, i'm still interested to develop application that can customize the mouse gaming button, for future development.